# NoReverseMatch at / in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

Hi Everyone i want to go on detail view but i get this error while paste the url

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'test' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['test/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

Here is my **Models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class article(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Content = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

Here is my **Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import (ListView,DetailView)
from .models import *
# Create your views here.

class Article(ListView):
    model = article

class Test(DetailView):
    model = article
```

Here is my **Urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from cbs import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.Article.as_view(),name="Article"),
    path('test/<int:pk>/', views.Test.as_view(),name="test"),
]
```

Here is my **Article_list.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% for article in article_list %}
      <h1><a href="{% url 'test' %}">{{ article.Title }}</a></h1>
    {% endfor %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your Article_list.html file you must change the href attribute on a tag to:

```
    <h1><a href="{% url 'test' article.id %}">{{ article.Title }}</a></h1>
```

to send id as parameter to the below url:

```
    path('test/<int:pk>/', views.Test.as_view(),name="test"),
```